# Layout broken after installing german language pack

Tags: magento2.3

I installed the german language pack from this site as descripted: https://github.com/splendidinternet/Magento2_German_LocalePack_de_DE

I copied all files to `/app/i18n/splendid/de_DE/`

- remove `rm pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/de_DE/js-translation.json`
- `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`
- `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
- `rm -rf var/di` **this folder does not exist**
- `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

After that the links and text are in german but the layout is broken:

[image]

In the source of the site the link to the file is:

```
 "baseUrl": "http://127.0.0.1/magento2/pub/static/version1604958349/frontend/Magento/luma/de_DE"
```

The number is equal with the number in the `deployed_version.txt` file.

The `pub\static` folder looks like:

[image]

**I think there is the folder missing with the version number in it.**

I cleaned the cache several times, deployed and did a reindex but this all does not work and I don't get the folder generated. What else can I do? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Run the below commands,

php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f de_DE
php bin/magento c:f
```

Comment: Thanks, I also had to add a .htaccess file